# Why doesn't mbed talk to my computer?

Tags: usb-device, mbed

I downloaded the driver to connect to [mbed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbed) via USB. I flashed a serial communications example program on the mbed board.

I've connected to it via [Tera Term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera_Term), at 9600 baud, 1 stop bit, no parity, and 8 data bits. I've also selected *LF for Receive* under terminal setup.

mbed is hooked via its standard program loading USB. Can I not use this one? I made it printf to both `USBSerial serial`, and `Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX)`.

Is my mbed device dead? Or am I missing something?

```
USBSerial serial;
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

int main(void) {
   uint8_t buf[128];
   pc.baud(9600);
   while(1)
   {
       serial.scanf("%s", buf);
       serial.printf("recv: %s", buf);
       pc.printf("recv: %s\r\n", buf);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the mbed example code, it appears that you cannot use both `USBSerial serial;` and `Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);`. What would be the point of that anyway? Just use `Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);`.